# Code Completion When Using Factory Class

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, phpdoc, code-completion

I am using Netbeans 8 for a Symfony2 project.
I have created a factory class for my model queries (they are static calls and mess up testing).
E.g

```
<?php
namespace My\Custom\Bundle\Classes\Factories;

use My\Custom\Bundle\Model\UserQuery;

class QueryFactory
{
    /**
     * Class name
     * @access public
     */
    const CLASS_NAME = __CLASS__;

    /**
     * newUserQuery()
     *
     * Creates a new user query object.
     * @access public
     * @return My\Custom\Bundle\Model\UserQuery
     */
    public function newUserQuery()
    {
        return UserQuery::create();
    }
}
```

What I want is for the auto complete to work on a variable that is created from a factory method (in this case the Propel methods for the User query).

```
<?php
namespace My\Custom\Bundle\Controller;

use My\Custom\Bundle\Classes\Factories\QueryFactory;

class ReportingController
{
    private $queryFactory;

    public function __construct(QueryFactory $query_factory)
    {
        $this->queryFactory = $query_factory;
    }

    public function fubar()
    {
        $user = $this->queryFactory->newUserQuery();
        // now want auto complete on the $user (in this case the propel methods)
        // $user->filterById(1);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is @return pointing to My\Custom\Bundle\Classes\Factories\My\Custom\Bundle\Model\UserQuery

try changing it to this

```
/**
* ...
* @return UserQuery
*/
```

Without the use statement it should be like this

```
/**
 * ...
 * @return \My\Custom\Bundle\Model\UserQuery
 */
```